# Mute/Unmute icons for html

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, icons

I have this buttons that mutes and unmutes audio but I have no icons for it and have been having trouble searching for them.

So far I have the play button &#9658 but wasn't able to find a good pause button to match and no mute unmute either.

If anyone knows how I can google for these "icons" please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of icons, fonts, image vector, raster ?

Answer (score 2):

If you use bootstrap, you can use their glyphicons.  The classes `glyphicon glyphicon-volume-off` and `glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up` would serve your needs admirably.

Comment: Thank you! I am inserting them now

Comment: It seems I am having trouble inserting "<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-volume-up"></span>" in innerHTML does it work?

Answer (score 1):

and .

I googled for "speaker unicode char".

Edit: and [⏸](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23f8/index.htm) for pause.

Comment: oh, unicode.. thanks! BTW I am using windows 7 and  and ⏸ doesn't show up for me (only the speaker)